# SQL: Using access,Trying to select all record from a form if a text box is nul

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to select all record from a table if a textbox "txtoccupation" is null or elese records that match the string in the texbox.

I follow a  guide and used the following line:

```
SELECT [EmpID]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[Education]
      ,[Occupation]
      ,[YearlyIncome]
      ,[Sales]
      ,[HireDate]
  FROM [Employee]
  WHERE Occupation = IIF(txtoccupation IS NULL, Occupation, txtoccupation)
```

It works at first sight, however in my table there are records where the "Occupation" field is empty, and the above line only select all record where there is at least some input in the "Occupation" field even if it is a  zero length string. What should be corrected if I also want to select records with the "Occupation" field being null if the textoccupation is null? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 WHERE txtoccupation IS NULL
    OR Occupation = txtoccupation
```

should do it. If `txtoccupation` is null, then the WHERE clause is true for all records.

Answer (score 0):

> What should be corrected if I also want to select records with the
> "Occupation" field being null if the textoccupation is null?

**Replace it with wildcard character**

You can change your `where` condition to :

```
WHERE Occupation LIKE IIF(ISNULL(txtoccupation), '%', txtoccupation);
```

Here is [ISNULL Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/isnull-function-f963233b-1c1e-4b0c-8bc3-3e8c0ea67c61#:%7E:text=Returns%20a%20Boolean%20value%20that,no%20valid%20data%20(Null).&text=The%20required%20expressionargument%20is%20a,numeric%20expression%20or%20string%20expression.&text=IsNull%20returns%20True%20if%20expression,%3B%20otherwise%2C%20IsNull%20returns%20False.)